# Exception caused by Jackson JsonMappingException - must be an interface

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-projections

I'm having a problem getting Projections to work with Joda `LocalDateTime`.

```
public interface SomeProjection {
   Long getId();
   LocalDateTime getDateCreated()
}
```

Results in the following error:

> Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException:
>   Projection type must be an interface! (through reference chain:
>   org.springframework.data.domain.PageImpl["content"]->java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList[0]->com.sun.proxy.$Proxy358["dateCreated"])

I tried adding the same conversion type that I have in the entity.

`@Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDateTime")`

But that doesn't seem to matter for Projections. Any tips or tricks here?

Comment: This looks to a bug in the latest spring data version for me. I get this error in one of my tests when trying to update to the latest version (while working with the previous version).

Edit: There is already an issue for that in their jira: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACMNS-1836